# Substitute of JObject

Tags: joomla-3.x

While creating custom component, I got to know that, JObject is deprecated. Keeping this in mind, What is the recommended method of creating blank Object. Do we have any substitution of JObject class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quote from @Bakual on [Github](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/6125):

***There is no class to replace it. JObject is a historic class which isn't really needed anymore with current PHP versions.***

***The error handling should instead be done using exceptions. Other than that it only contains some setter and getter methods. Either create own set/get methods in your class or use for example our Registry class if you need more advanced property handling.***

---

So if you need to create a blank object, you can use the following:

```
$blank = new stdClass();
```

Comment: @SahilPurav - You're welcome, glad it helped

Comment: Quick question: why are you casting it to an object? You already get an object.

Comment: @ValentinDespa - I could be wrong, but if an an array of data is stored as an object, I think it needs to be defined. Of course, the OP would like a blank object, but just in case I suppose. Please tell me if I'm completely wrong :/

Comment: If you have an array, you can convert (cast) it to an object. But you are clearly creating a new object, so the converting it to a object make no sense (of course, it does not do harm). See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php